# How to get the number of elements in a hash array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a hash array with the following data:

```
$result->{data} = [
          {
            'SubFeatured' => '0',
            'SubHearingImpaired' => '0',
            'SubAuthorComment' => undef,
            'SubDownloadLink' => 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-308688c2a2/1952675182.gz',
            'MovieNameEng' => undef,
            'SubDownloadsCnt' => '1836',
            'MovieName' => '"Merlin" The Witch\'s Quickening',
            'LanguageName' => 'English',
            'MovieFPS' => '25.000',
            'SeriesIMDBParent' => '1199099',
            'MovieHash' => 'a03eeb674b4c355c',
            'SeriesEpisode' => '11',
            'UserNickName' => undef,
            'MovieYear' => '2009',
            'SubSize' => '33290',
            'MovieKind' => 'episode',
            'IDSubMovieFile' => '1852103',
            'ZipDownloadLink' => 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subad/src-api/vrf-7920df6fe7/4001829',
            'SubBad' => '0',
            'ISO639' => 'en',
            'IDSubtitle' => '4001829',
            'MovieReleaseName' => 'Merlin 02x11 The Witch\'s Quickening DVDRip HAGGiS',
            'MatchedBy' => 'moviehash',
            'MovieTimeMS' => '0',
            'UserID' => '0',
            'SubFormat' => 'srt',
            'MovieByteSize' => '365428736',
            'SubRating' => '10.0',
            'SubComments' => '0',
            'SubActualCD' => '1',
            'SubHash' => '791313d38bfb1eedd5d1c8985b72a7d3',
            'UserRank' => undef,
            'IDSubtitleFile' => '1952675182',
            'SubSumCD' => '1',
            'SubFileName' => 'Merlin - 02x11 - The Witch\'s Quickening.DVDRip.HAGGiS.English.orig.Addic7ed.com.srt',
            'SubAddDate' => '2010-12-10 20:55:54',
            'IDMovieImdb' => '1558034',
            'SubtitlesLink' => 'http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/4001829/merlin-the-witch-s-quickening-en',
            'IDMovie' => '100498',
            'SeriesSeason' => '2',
            'SubHD' => '0',
            'SubLanguageID' => 'eng',
            'MovieImdbRating' => '8.1'
          },
          {
            'SubFeatured' => '0',
            'SubHearingImpaired' => '0',
            'SubAuthorComment' => undef,
            'SubDownloadLink' => 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-69741ece04/1953248198.gz',
            'MovieNameEng' => undef,
            'SubDownloadsCnt' => '340',
            'MovieName' => '"Merlin" The Witch\'s Quickening',
            'LanguageName' => 'English',
            'MovieFPS' => '25.000',
            'SeriesIMDBParent' => '1199099',
            'MovieHash' => 'a03eeb674b4c355c',
            'SeriesEpisode' => '11',
            'UserNickName' => undef,
            'MovieYear' => '2009',
            'SubSize' => '33286',
            'MovieKind' => 'episode',
            'IDSubMovieFile' => '5485801',
            'ZipDownloadLink' => 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subad/src-api/vrf-e53ed25c1a/4702165',
            'SubBad' => '0',
            'ISO639' => 'en',
            'IDSubtitle' => '4702165',
            'MovieReleaseName' => ' merlin.s02e11',
            'MatchedBy' => 'moviehash',
            'MovieTimeMS' => '0',
            'UserID' => '0',
            'SubFormat' => 'srt',
            'MovieByteSize' => '365428736',
            'SubRating' => '0.0',
            'SubComments' => '0',
            'SubActualCD' => '1',
            'SubHash' => '9a4f979c8bf8d1e5167fe2954e94b7c1',
            'UserRank' => undef,
            'IDSubtitleFile' => '1953248198',
            'SubSumCD' => '1',
            'SubFileName' => 'merlin.s02e11.srt',
            'SubAddDate' => '2012-10-29 18:33:26',
            'IDMovieImdb' => '1558034',
            'SubtitlesLink' => 'http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/4702165/merlin-the-witch-s-quickening-en',
            'IDMovie' => '100498',
            'SeriesSeason' => '2',
            'SubHD' => '0',
            'SubLanguageID' => 'eng',
            'MovieImdbRating' => '8.1'
          },
          {
            'SubFeatured' => '0',
            'SubHearingImpaired' => '0',
            'SubAuthorComment' => undef,
            'SubDownloadLink' => 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-025968d0b0/1953259955.gz',
            'MovieNameEng' => undef,
            'SubDownloadsCnt' => '472',
            'MovieName' => '"Merlin" The Witch\'s Quickening',
            'LanguageName' => 'English',
            'MovieFPS' => '25.000',
            'SeriesIMDBParent' => '1199099',
            'MovieHash' => 'a03eeb674b4c355c',
            'SeriesEpisode' => '11',
            'UserNickName' => undef,
            'MovieYear' => '2009',
            'SubSize' => '33456',
            'MovieKind' => 'episode',
            'IDSubMovieFile' => '9097729',
            'ZipDownloadLink' => 'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subad/src-api/vrf-9226ed7194/4714102',
            'SubBad' => '0',
            'ISO639' => 'en',
            'IDSubtitle' => '4714102',
            'MovieReleaseName' => ' Merlin 2x11',
            'MatchedBy' => 'moviehash',
            'MovieTimeMS' => '0',
            'UserID' => '0',
            'SubFormat' => 'srt',
            'MovieByteSize' => '365428736',
            'SubRating' => '0.0',
            'SubComments' => '0',
            'SubActualCD' => '1',
            'SubHash' => '07a4a8902093b1e578d46875b214fb27',
            'UserRank' => undef,
            'IDSubtitleFile' => '1953259955',
            'SubSumCD' => '1',
            'SubFileName' => 'Merlin 2x11.srt',
            'SubAddDate' => '2012-11-12 19:40:13',
            'IDMovieImdb' => '1558034',
            'SubtitlesLink' => 'http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/4714102/merlin-the-witch-s-quickening-en',
            'IDMovie' => '100498',
            'SeriesSeason' => '2',
            'SubHD' => '0',
            'SubLanguageID' => 'eng',
            'MovieImdbRating' => '8.1'
          }
        ];
```

My code requires that I get the number of elements in the array `$result->{data}`. However I am unsure of the proper method of doing so.

I tried:
`scalar $result->{data}` which prints out `ARRAY(0x35cedf8)`

I know little about hashes, and how to properly use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number of elements in the `$results->{data}` array ref, you were close, but you just need to deref the array with the `@{ }` operator.

If you want the number of elements in (each) hash ref within the array, you can accomplish that with the similar `%{ }` operator (just a plain `%$_` in this case).

Here are both:

```
printf "Top level arrays: %2d\n", scalar @{$result->{data}};
printf "   Hash elements: %2d\n", scalar keys %$_ for @{$result->{data}};
```

This outputs:

```
Top level arrays:  3
   Hash elements: 43
   Hash elements: 43
   Hash elements: 43
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to dereference that array reference:

```
$foo = @{ $result->{data} };
```

or

```
print scalar @{ $result->{data} };
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a hash array

No. You have an array reference. Each element within the referenced array is a hash reference.